# React-Native cannot manually link libraries on XCode

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, libraries

I can't manually link any libraries on xcode, on a react-native project that use pod...

There is a part of my `package.json` file

```json
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.4.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
  }
  ...
```

and this is a part of my `Podfile`

```rb
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

  ...

  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  use_native_modules!
end
```

Comment: manual linking is not required from version 0.59+ you can unlink all and just say `npm i rn-fetch-blob` and it will autolink.

Comment: unfortunately `rn-fetch-blob` throw an error

Comment: what was the error?